# Get Product name related to a store view at admin

Tags: magento-1.8

I have created two store views for two different languages, english and arabic.  I displayed the store view at admin form for my module just above tabs as shown below:

[image]

When i select a store view, the page reloads and in module form i place the following code:

```
$storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($storeId);
  foreach($products as $p)
    {
        $p->load($p->getId);

        if($p->getId() == 166)
        {
            echo $p->getName();
        }
```

I have different names for each store view, but here i only get the name for the default store view which is English, and i want the name of the product entered for that specific store view.

I have used the below code to get the product store ids for checking:

```
$p->getStoreIds();
```

and i get correct ids for my store views which are 1 for english and 4 for arabic.

I am not sure if i am doing it correct or wrong, but can some one provide me some guidance here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `$p->load($p->getId());` without specifying a store view, you will get the default values.

Try this instead.

```
$p->setStoreId($storeId)->load($p->getId());
```

Comment: It worked. Can you please explain to me that then what is the purpose of addStoreFilter at collection?

Comment: If you are in the backend it has not effect. On frontend I think it joins with the price index table for that specific store view or something like that.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it has no effect on backend. Just removed adStoreFilter and still it is working fine. Thanks for the answer.